# How to sort the count received after reading multiple files

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and need help for sorting using HashMap or TreeMap.I need to display the count of total no. of disconnects corresponding to a particular computer name.User enters the date range for which the computer name and count is displayed.Data is read from multiple files which contain data like:
FILE 1

```
[C417] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900 (locked) LanId: | (11/23 11:36:13) | Client is disconnected from agent.
[C417] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900 (locked) LanId: | (11/23 11:36:13) | Client is connected to agent
```

FILE 2:

```
[C445] ComputerName:FRONTOFFICE UserID:YB Yenae Ball Station 7A  LanId: | (11/23 17:01:55) | Client is disconnected from agent.
[C445] ComputerName:KCUTSHALL-PC UserID:GO kcutshall Station 9900 (locked) LanId: | (11/23 17:02:00) | Client is disconnected from agent.
```

OUTPUT REQUIRED:

```
Computer Name    No. of disconnects
KCUTSHALL-PC          2
FRONTOFFICE           1
```

No. of disconnects should be in descending order.I tried doing with HashMap but didnt get the desired output.Please edit my code or show me how can I get a consolidated count while reading through multiple files.Thanks a lot in advance. Here is what I wrote

```
enter code here
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;


public class ReadZip{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    try {
Scanner input1=new Scanner(System.in);

   Scanner input2=new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Enter start date");
    String userDate1=input1.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter end date");
     String userDate2=input2.nextLine();
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM/dd");
      Date d1=df.parse(userDate1);
      Date d2=df.parse(userDate2);

      ZipFile zf=new ZipFile("C:\\Users\\Engineeir\\Desktop\\QoS_logs.zip");
      Enumeration entries=zf.entries();

      BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
          System.in));
      while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
        ZipEntry ze=(ZipEntry) entries.nextElement();

     BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(zf.getInputStream(ze)));
        String line; String name;String compnames;int lines=0;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null) {

       String[] st=line.split("\\|",-1);
if(st.length>1){
String dates=st[1];
 String[] parts=dates.split("-");
 SimpleDateFormat f=new SimpleDateFormat("(MM/dd");
String[] ob=parts[0].split(" ");
String finaldate=ob[1];
HashMap first=new HashMap(); 
Date d3=f.parse(finaldate);
if((d3.after(d1) && d3.before(d2)) && line.contains("Client is disconnected from agent")==true)
{
compnames=getName(st);
lines++;}

else{break;}
first.put(compnames,lines);
ArrayList as=new ArrayList(first.entrySet());  

        Collections.sort(as,new Comparator(){  
            public int compare(Object o1,Object o2)  
            {  
                Map.Entry e1=(Map.Entry)o1 ;  
                Map.Entry e2=(Map.Entry)o2 ;  
                Integer first=(Integer)e1.getValue();  
                Integer second=(Integer)e2.getValue();  
                return second.compareTo(first);  
            }  
  });
  Iterator i=as.iterator();  
        while(i.hasNext())  
        {  
            System.out.println((Map.Entry)i.next());  
        }

}



       //br.close();
}  }  }catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }}

      public static String getName(String[] st)
    {
       String[] name=st[0].split("\\:",-1);
       String[] comp=name[1].split("\\ ",-1);

        return(comp[0]);
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort the entries in a `Map` by their values, not without really evil, dirty, and unsafe hacks.  (That said...I also find your lack of generics disturbing.)

Your best bet is to do something like

```
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries =
  new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(entries, Collections.reverseOrder( // for descending order
  new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
    public int compare(
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry1,
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2) {
      return entry1.getValue().compareTo(entry2.getValue());
    }
  });
```

which is basically what you're already doing -- so basically, you already have the right way to do this.

Comment: `"You cannot sort the entries in a Map"...` what about: [The Sorted Map Interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/sorted-map.html).

Comment: you should check that the entries in the `compare` methods are not null

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Sorry, I meant sorting by _values_.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: We're getting the map entries from a `Map` that's been already initialized; based on how the OP initialized the map, there's no possiblility of null entries or null values.

Comment: @LouisWasserman:I'm not getting the count in a sorted order and also I'm unable to get a consolidated count going from one file to other.

Comment: @user1297592, you don't appear to be putting data into your `Map` correctly...or possibly at all?  Your code is _extremely_ hard to follow, but you should be initializing a `HashMap<String, Integer>` once, outside of the loop, putting entries inside of the loop, and then doing the sorting and analysis after the loop ends.

Comment: That said, if I were you, I would seriously consider rewriting the entire program with proper indentation, generics, and other simple techniques for making your program readable without squinting at it for a while.